# SQL + VBA Populating Data in Cell Range

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I currently have a code that is connecting to SQL database in VBA.  The data is populating correctly as I would like however, I was wondering if there is a way to condense the code below.  I have 4 different columns and 26 rows and I feel like if I go this route, I will be wasting a lot of time.  I want the range to go from C20:C45 and the results to show from cells H20:H45.  Can some one help?  Thanks!

```
    ' Open the connection and execute data for WFTEs.
   Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT sum(Hours)/80 FROM payroll2015_rif WHERE DepartmentCode = '" & Range("$E$6") & "' AND payperiod = '" & Range("C20") & "' and paycode IN ('REG1', 'REG2');")
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets(2).Range("$H20").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close


' Open the connection and execute data for WFTEs.
   Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT sum(Hours)/80 FROM payroll2015_rif WHERE DepartmentCode = '" & Range("$E$6") & "' AND payperiod = '" & Range("C21") & "' and paycode IN ('REG1', 'REG2');")
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets(2).Range("$H21").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give enough information to answer this, but it sounds like it should go to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) anyway.

Comment: Is this code working as intended or not?

Comment: Thanks, I posted the question in Code Review with more code.  Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: You could aggregate the data for all pay periods at the same time instead of pulling it 1 by 1. You'll need to add payperiod to the SELECT in your SQL and GROUP BY it. Use the ADO you've already written to dump the results to your desired cell range.

Comment: Yes @nhgrif, the code is working as intended.  I am trying to "condense" the code if possible so it can populate values based on the range.  Hope I am making sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could do the trick? Basically I would take the relevant values from the Excel ranges and put them into arrays in VBA, create an array of results by looping through the variables, and then throw the array back into the excel Range.

Note I didn't include the ADODB connection and recordset declarations which I assume you have somewhere in your code.

```
Sub myLoop()

    Dim dept As String
    Dim payperiod As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    dept = Range("E6")
    payperiod = Range("C20:C45")
    ReDim result(1 To UBound(payperiod), 1 To 1)

    'don't forget to set your ADODB stuff somewhere

    For i = 1 To UBound(payperiod)
        Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT sum(Hours)/80 FROM payroll2015_rif WHERE DepartmentCode = '" & dept & "' AND payperiod = '" & payperiod(i,1) & "' and paycode IN ('REG1', 'REG2');")
        result(i, 1) = rs(0)
        rs.Close
    Next i

    Range("H20:H45") = result

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this up and try some pseudo code. First we'll tackle the SQL portion of your problem:

```
SELECT payperiod
     , calc = SUM(Hours) / 80
FROM payroll2015_rif
WHERE DepartmentCode = <DepartmentCode>
  AND payperiod IN (<PayPeriods>)
  AND paycode IN ('REG1', 'REG2')
GROUP BY payperiod
```

Now we need to replace anything wrapped in < > with a value from Excel. You've figured out **DepartmentCode** already so we'll work on pay period. SQL is expecting something like `'Period 1', 'Period 2', 'Period 3'` to be passed to the `IN` clause here.

A very naive approach would be:

```
Set strValues = Range("C21") & ', ' & Range("C22") & ', ' & Range("C23")
```

This is tedious but could easily be refactored into a loop or something. Putting this together with the example you already have should give you what you want.

Comment: I am having a hard time with the destination, I guess.  The range right now says H20:H45 but only populates H20.  My current code is:
Sheets(2).Range(H20:H45).CopyFromRecordset rs

Comment: I forgot to add the payperiod column and a `GROUP BY` to the query. Without these changes the query will return a single result for all periods instead of a result for each period. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Sorry, @kittoes, that did not work.  I had to modify the code because it gave me a type mismatch error.  Here's what I have:

`Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT sum(Hours)/80 " & _
          "FROM payroll2015_rif " & _
          "WHERE DepartmentCode = '" & Range("$E$6") & "' " & _
          "AND payperiod IN (" & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & ")" & _
          "AND paycode IN ('REG1', 'REG2') " & _
          "GROUP BY payperiod;")

          
          ' Transfer result.
Sheets(2).Range("$F20:F45").CopyFromRecordset rs`